# In App Purchases in iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, in-app-purchase

I have developed an application with in App Purchases. I have the following code... In the ViewController.m file I the butoon1Clicked Method I am callInAppPurchases. Actually when click on the button first time i want to perform In App Purchases. If the Transaction is Successful, from the next Click I want to Perform Some Action (For Example I gave NSLog Statement) Where Should I have to write the NSLog stmt(or any code) in the program to perform the Action when i click on the button after A successful Transaction. Please Exaplain me where i have to write. Or Explain me in any process. I thought i want to handle with BOOL Values but i am not able to know where i have to set the BOOL Value as YES / NO. Please Explain me... MyStoreObserver.m file do the In App Purchase Transactions.

ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender
{       
     [self callInAppPurchase];
     NSLoG(@"Perform Some Action");
}
#pragma mark-In-AppPurchase code from here
-(void)callInAppPurchase
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        // Display a store to the user.     
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyStoreAbserver.h"
@interface iTeach_MathsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    BOOL isPurchased,isFailed;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isPurchased,isFailed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

      MyStoreAbserver *observer = [[MyStoreAbserver alloc] init];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
      if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isPurchased"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
       self.isPurchased = YES;
     else
       isPurchased = NO;
     isFailed = NO;

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: No one's going to read that wall of code. reduce your problem to something easier to understand.

Comment: Yep Marc is right. You should at least make out problem or find the small are of your problem.

Comment: I have reduced the code...  Now Please look at my Question once...

Answer (score 0):

I think [you refer this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases), and implement code... This link is useful for me...

When product purchase you call this function:

```
 (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Comment: @elpaa... Ihave done my coding using that link... My InAPP Purchase transactions are working fine... Just simple thing... I am not able to know where should I have to write the code in my application to perform an action when a button is Clicked after successful Transaction...

Comment: if you are use link code , use this function (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification in .m file ,after your product is successfully purchase then this function call